# How can you add one each time to a random array?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating this function where you get a random number and assign it to the grid empty array. I want that this randomIndex increases by 1 each time it loops. I've tried doing `grid[randomIndex + 1]` but it does nothing.

```
let grid = []
  for (var i = 0; i < 110; i++) {
      grid.push(<div className="boxGrid"></div>)
  }

const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random());

  for (var index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    console.log(grid[randomIndex])
}
```

Comment: At first, your `randomIndex` is always `0` because `Math.random()` returns a number between `0` and `1` (exclusive). You should multiply `Math.random()` with an appropriate factor before rounding it. Secondly, write `grid[randomIndex + index]` instead of `grid[randomIndex]` to add 0,1,2,3,4 to your precalculated random index (offset).

Answer (score 0):

You should make the range of the random number to be in `{0,...,grid.length-1}`, so you need to multiply `Math.random()` by `grid.length`.

It seems you then want to get a consecutive *slice* of your grid, starting at the random index.

In that case you should ensure that the random number is not too close to the end of the grid, so you can still take those 5 entries. Limit the range of the random pick with 4, and to get the slice, you can just use the `slice` method:

```
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (grid.length - 5));
const result = grid.slice(randomIndex, randomIndex + 5);
console.log(result);
```